# How can get an associated value using codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to load an associated value with 2 ids joined but its not showing the value.

I have 2 tables: patients (id, name) and  attributes (id, patient_id, name,description2,created_at) and I'm trying to display the patient name.

Here is the controller: **app/controllers/Attributes.php**

```
    public function fetchAttributeValueData($patient_id)
{
    $result = array('data' => array());

    $data = $this->model_attributes->getAttributeValueData($patient_id);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        // button
        $buttons = '
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editFunc('.$value['id'].')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeFunc('.$value['id'].')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeModal"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        ';

        $result['data'][$key] = array(
            $value['patient_id'],
            $value['name'],
            $value['descripcion2'],
            $value['created_at'],
            $buttons
        );
    } // /foreach

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Here is the model: app/models/Model_attributes.php

```
    public function getAttributeValueData($id = null)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM odontograms WHERE patient_id = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
             $this->db->join('patients','patients.id = odontograms.patient_id');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I tried:

```
                $value['patients.name'],
```

2nd tried:

```
                $value['patients']['name'],
```

3rd tried:

```
                $patients['name'],
```

Comment: i think there is wrong with your query

Comment: What is the result of `print_r($data);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function getAttributeValueData($id = NULL)
{

    if(is_null($id)) return false;

    $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.* FROM odontograms AS a 
            JOIN patients AS b ON a.patient_id = b.id 
            WHERE a.patient_id = ? 
            ORDER BY a.created_at DESC";

    $query = $this->db->query( $sql , array( $id ) );
    
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Then you can foreach like your third example

Comment: i tried your code and also  $patients['name'], ...........  $value['patients']['name'].....$value['patients.name']   nothing is working

Comment: i tried your code and also  $patients['name'], ...........  $value['patients']['name'].....$value['patients.name']   nothing is working......also i tried $key['patients']['name'] but is not displaying value $patients.['name']  ......$key[$patients]['name']this show issue convert to string

Comment: did you try to var_dump or print_r , $patients? before looping?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Your code is working perfect just change description2 name]You can use **active Record**...
for example

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('odontograms');
$this->db->order_by('odontograms.created_at', 'DESC');
$this->db->join('patients', 'patients.id = odontograms.patient_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Ok but how can display it on the Array controller?

Comment: its not displaying error, maybe i don't don't how to show errors but values are not displaying........i'm doing this on controller $result['data'][$key] = array(
    $patients['name'],   when i use your code

Comment: @CarlosMorales you have typos mistake in $value['descripcion2'] change it to $value['description2']